# audit tool is unable to capture the bash(write operations) events

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, kernel

I have the following configuration in my system

```
OS : ubuntu 14.04
Kernel version : 3.13.0-32-generic
```

I have following rules in my `audit.rules` file.

```
-w /etc/     -p wa -k system_configuration_change
-w /usr/bin  -p wa -k system_binary_change
-w /usr/sbin -p wa -k system_binary_change
-w /bin/     -p wa -k system_binary_change
```

now if i create a file inside `/etc/` directory ,

```
touch myfile
chmod 666 myfile
echo "Something!!!" > myfile
```

Here I triggered 3 events but `audit` is unable to catch the last event of writing content into the file.

```
$ egrep --only-matching 'node=.*$' /log-collector/audit.log | ausearch -f myfile -ui 0 -c touch
```

This is giving expected output but

```
$ egrep --only-matching 'node=.*$' /log-collector/audit.log | ausearch -f myfile -ui 0 -c chmod
```

This is giving expected output but

```
$egrep --only-matching 'node=.*$' /log-collector/audit.log | ausearch -f myfile -ui 0 -c bash
```

no matches

This same command is working fine in *ubuntu 12.04* with kernel version of 3.2.0-76-generic.

Here i am trying to change the kernel but it is saying 3.2.0-76-generic is not compatible with *ubuntu 14.04* according to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack.

Please help me out.

Regards,
BhavaniPrasad